# SP2013 - Disable DDL choices based on permissions

Tags: permissions, dropdown, choice-field

Here's one I've been trying to figure out - I hope you can help:

I'm trying to find a way to disable certain options that exist in a drop down list, based on the user's permission.  For example, let's say we have a choice field DDL with options A, B, C, D, and E.  A user that is in a permissions group called "Vowels Only" would be able to choose A and E from the list, but not the other letters.

I've tried using workflows and js, but can't come up with anything that works so far.  Any ideas?

Comment: On list form page, you need to check the current users permissions (if the user is present in the particular group or not). If user is not found in the group you can disable the options using simple jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box (or with WF). You would have to develop custom filed definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can create *second list B with the A, B, C, D and E choices* and **create lookup in first list A pointing to records in list B.** Set appropriate permissions on records in list B and users will be able to choice only choices like A,D from list B only where they will have permissions on it.

*It's permission based filtering.*